# Move grouping field from tablix rows to header

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am creating an SSRS report that has a datasource with the following fields (and sample data):

```
StartDate |  EndDate  | GroupId | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------------------------------|
01-Jan-16 | 06-Jan-16 |   G1    |    11   |   23
01-Jan-16 | 06-Jan-16 |   G2    |    28   |   47
01-Jan-16 | 06-Jan-16 |   G3    |    14   |    8
07-Jan-16 | 20-Jan-16 |   G1    |     7   |   15
07-Jan-16 | 20-Jan-16 |   G3    |    34   |   16
21-Jan-16 | 31-Jan-16 |   G2    |     3   |   11
21-Jan-16 | 31-Jan-16 |   G3    |     9   |   23
21-Jan-16 | 31-Jan-16 |   G4    |    16   |    2
```

I need to group this data by period (represented by the StartDate and EndDate fields), display the dates on top of the page and list the rest of the fields (GroupId, Amount1 and Amount2) in a table/matrix. Something like that:

```
StartDate: 01-Jan-16
EndDate:   06-Jan-16

GroupId | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------|
   G1   |    11   |   23
   G2   |    28   |   47
   G3   |    14   |    8

-- new page --

StartDate: 07-Jan-16
EndDate:   20-Jan-16

GroupId | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------|
   G1   |     7   |   15
   G3   |    34   |   16

-- new page --

StartDate: 21-Jan-16
EndDate:   31-Jan-16

GroupId | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------|
   G2   |     3   |   11
   G3   |     9   |   23
   G4   |    16   |    2
```

I have tried using Tablix, but the closest representation I could come up with was

```
StartDate |  EndDate  | GroupId | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------------------------------|
01-Jan-16 | 06-Jan-16 |   G1    |    11   |   23
          |           |   G2    |    28   |   47
          |           |   G3    |    14   |    8

-- new page --

StartDate |  EndDate  | GroupId | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------------------------------|
07-Jan-16 | 20-Jan-16 |   G1    |     7   |   15
          |           |   G3    |    34   |   16

-- new page --

StartDate |  EndDate  | GroupId | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------------------------------|
21-Jan-16 | 31-Jan-16 |   G2    |     3   |   11
          |           |   G3    |     9   |   23
          |           |   G4    |    16   |    2
```

That is, I could not move the dates outside of the rows to the header.

Any idea how I can achieve the required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: When adding the parent group, check the check box says "Add group header"

Comment: You're right. If I use 'Add group header' when creating the group then I can display this information in any of the group header fields above grouped data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the matrix do not use Start Date and End Date. 
In the list use a text box and map with the dataset. Select the list and in the RowGroup right click the details, select group properties. In the General Tab, under group expression, there is group on.. In that group on Add your start date and end date

[image]